# Deploying Several Instances of an App with Presto

Tags: deployment, automated-deploy, presto

I have an app that I want to deploy, but I need to deploy several instances of the app on the same server. Each instance needs to have a different unit ID in its app.config file. How can I do that?

I set up the app:

[image]

Then I created the variables:

[image]

But when I try to add the second instance to the server, I get this message:

[image]

How can I add another instance, and have each use unique unit ID variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If deployment instances vary by a certain variable, simply create those separate variables:

[image]

They'll look like this:

[image]

[image]

Then, on the servers tab, you can enter as many instances of that app as you'd like, as long as they each have a different override group.

[image]

Now, when these are deployed, each app instance will use the unit ID value in the override group specified for that app.

Hope that helps.